# Python - wget does not work with storing print in file

Tags: python

I have this file:

```
import wget
import sys
import datetime
class Printer(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for file in self.files:
            file.write(obj)
            file.flush()
    def flush(self):
        for file in self.files:
            file.flush()

f = open(f"{__file__}-{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.log", 'w')
sys.stdout = Printer(sys.stdout, f)
url='https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt'
wget.download(url)
#Your print statements below
print("Hello world!")
```

My above code does not work. It does not download the file. The question is to make the download work while storing the print logs in the log file.

Comment: I simply tried these two lines - ```url='https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt'
wget.download(url)``` and this works for me, it did download that file.

Answer (score 1):

The [`wget`](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) python package downloads content of a URL in a file. Below is a working example:

```
import wget
url = 'https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt'
filename = wget.download(url)
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I want to store my print statements in log.